# How optuna narrow the search scope step by step, by using the bayesian method

Tags: bayesian, optuna

How optuna narrow the search scope step by step, by using the bayesian method. Can you give a simple example ?

My first instinct is like binary search. Just like, searching mid=(l+r)/2 after searching l and r, and then choose the better one between the interval [l, mid) and [mid, r). But this way assumes there is one unique optimal point. What if there are multiple optimal points ?